# Не работает поиск по маске

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот код:

```
private bool IsCanInteract(Entity entity)
    {
        Debug.Log(LayerMask.LayerToName(entity.gameObject.layer));
        Debug.Log((_checkEntitiesMask.value & (1 << entity.gameObject.layer)));
        if ((_checkEntitiesMask.value & (1 << entity.gameObject.layer)) != 0)
        {
            Debug.Log(true);
            return true;
        }
        Debug.Log(false);
        return false;
    }
```

В дебаге возвращается нужный слой(скажем, Entity), но следующие дебаги выводят 0 и false.

В LayerMask _checkEntitiesMask указан нужный слой Entity.

Почему может не работать?

Comment: Пример данных нужен. "нужный" ни о чем не говорит.

Comment: https://ibb.co/z4xv4BD